# Rails: Sending POST data to both local and remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, post, salesforce

I have a form which I'd like to save through a standard RESTful rails pattern, but I also need to insert a lead into SalesForce via post. Admittedly I'm quite a newbie on this - any suggestions on the most elegant way to do this?

Cheers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive the form and then, inside your controller, you make a call to Salesforce, possibly using something like [RestClient](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client)

```
def create
  @your_object = MyObject.new(params[:my_object])
  @your_object.save
  SalesforceService.post( @your_object )
  redirect_to home_path
end
```

You could also use [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) to make this call in a background worker to make your requests faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following after your model save is successful.

```
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(SALESFORCE_URL),
            {'param_name1' => param_value1})
result = res.body
```

Or use a salesforce gem to do that update.  Something like http://rubygems.org/gems/activesalesforce